# Test if class is in module before importing the module

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

Is it possible to test if a class is in a module before importing the module?

Given **root_package.sub_package.some_module.a_class** I would like to see if **some_module** has an attribute **a_class** before attempting to import **the module** using importlib.

I can write custom code to test for the **a_class** definition in the module source file but was hoping for standard library functionality to do this with.

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    from module import Class
    # remove imported class if you just need to test
    del Class
    print("Found")
except ImportError:
    print("Not Found")
```